# error in using switch case

Tags: c++, codeblocks, char-pointer

in the following code:

```
    switch(a)
    {

    case '+' :
        result=num1+num2;
    break;

    case '-' :
        result=num1-num2;
    break;

    case '*' :
        result=num1*num2;
    break;

    case '/' :
        result=num1/num2;
    break;

    case '^' :
        result=pow(num1,num2);
    break;

    default :
       cout << "Invalid operator" << endl;
    }
```

is the char pointer, and the error is:
error: switch quantity not an integer...

Comment: I don't understand, is a a char or char pointer. If it's a char pointer, that would explain why you are getting an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `a` is a pointer, you cannot use it in the `switch`: you need to dereference it first - either like this

```
switch(*a)
```

or like this

```
switch(a[0])
```

Comment: Yep, this. I would guess if a is a char *, then that would explain the error.

Comment: thaks for that, it's working correctly